# Thévenin equivalent with a dependent source

Tags: thevenin

I'm working in a circuit with some switches and it has the same configuration but different elements between ab. I am not sure if is possible to get a Thévenin equivalent of the next strange subicircuit to simplify calculations:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPAKDx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What exactly does "next strange subicircuit to simplify calculations" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since \$i_x \$ is not associated in any way with the output port *AB*, \$i_x\$ is an independent variable and thus, as seen from the port *AB*, the CCVS is an *independent* source.  The Thevenin equivalent is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUVF3w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>